# LEFT JOIN query returns multiple results

Tags: mysql

I have the query below which looks at a table of data in which each line has an ID, date/time and key action (as well as other data).  This table cannot be changed and is out of my control.

The query finds an occurrence of the Create action (which is always the first) pulls the ID and Date/Time for Creation and then pulls the Date/Time of the other key actions (Add Info, Book Appt, Accept) in one row of data:

```
SELECT _create.ID AS ID, 
_create.`datetime` AS Create, 
_inform.`datetime` AS Add_Info,
_bookap.`datetime` AS Book_Appt,
_accept.`datetime` AS Accept,
FROM table AS _create
LEFT JOIN table AS _inform ON (_create.ID = _inform.ID AND _inform.action = 'Add Info')
LEFT JOIN table AS _bookap ON (_create.ID = _bookap.ID AND _bookap.action = 'Book Appt')
LEFT JOIN table AS _accept ON (_create.ID = _accept.ID AND _accept.action = 'Accept')
WHERE _create.action="Create"
```

So I get something like:

```
ID  -  Create Date - Inform Date - Bookap Date - Accept Date
1234   01/02/2013    02/02/2013    09/02/2013    10/02/2013
```

This works well.

However if the query finds 2 events of the same type ie 'Book Appt' for the same ID, which can happen sometimes, it pulls two lines of data for that ID.  So I get:

```
ID  -  Create Date - Inform Date - Bookap Date - Accept Date
1234   01/02/2013    02/02/2013    09/02/2013    10/02/2013 
1234   01/02/2013    02/02/2013    15/02/2013    10/02/2013
```

I need it to ignore the second occurence and only return one line per ID.  Or, even better return a line showing Bookap Date1 and Bookap Date2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Use `GROUP BY` to group the records into one row, and [`min()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) to select the earliest event date.

```
SELECT _create.ID AS ID, 
min(_create.`datetime`) AS Create, 
min(_inform.`datetime`) AS Add_Info,
min(_bookap.`datetime`) AS Book_Appt,
min(_accept.`datetime`) AS Accept,
FROM table AS _create
LEFT JOIN table AS _inform ON (_create.ID = _inform.ID AND _inform.action = 'Add Info')
LEFT JOIN table AS _bookap ON (_create.ID = _bookap.ID AND _bookap.action = 'Book Appt')
LEFT JOIN table AS _accept ON (_create.ID = _accept.ID AND _accept.action = 'Accept')
WHERE _create.action="Create"
GROUP BY _create.ID;
```

A quick and dirty way to show all event dates but still return one row is to use the [`group_concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function instead of [`min()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) in the query above. This would put multiple `datetime`s into single columns which your app layer would then need to parse.

Comment: Thanks for this, it makes sense.  However pre-GROUP BY the query took 8 secs to return 30 lines (LIMIT 30).  Now it seems to run forever (well 3 mins and counting...) Any idea why?

Comment: @highfidelity run EXPLAIN SELECT .... and show us the output. Though it should probably be a separate question.

Comment: As per comments to Mike below, the index on ID was missing.  Havnt added this the query runs very quickly now

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use `GROUP BY _create.ID` after your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  Your comment, like the others has been helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return multiple `Book_Appt` values in a single row, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` like this:

```
SELECT _create.ID AS ID, 
_create.`datetime` AS Create, 
_inform.`datetime` AS Add_Info,
GROUP_CONCAT(_bookap.`datetime`) AS Book_Appt,
_accept.`datetime` AS Accept,
FROM table AS _create
LEFT JOIN table AS _inform ON (_create.ID = _inform.ID AND _inform.action = 'Add Info')
LEFT JOIN table AS _bookap ON (_create.ID = _bookap.ID AND _bookap.action = 'Book Appt')
LEFT JOIN table AS _accept ON (_create.ID = _accept.ID AND _accept.action = 'Accept')
WHERE _create.action="Create"
GROUP BY `ID`
```

This would return a comma-seperated list of datetime values in your case.

So your output might look like

```
ID  -  Create Date - Inform Date - Bookap Date      -       Accept Date
1234   01/02/2013    02/02/2013    09/02/2013,15/02/2013    10/02/2013
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. This would be ideal, but as per my comments above to Asaph, the query which previously ran in 8 seconds now just runs and runs - any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have an index on `_create.ID` and on `_create.action`?

Comment: Doh! Index missing on ID.  Now working well.  Thanks for coming back to me - a great help :)

Comment: Also I should have mentioned you need to make sure you have an index on any fields used in the join conditions as well, so `_inform.ID`, `_inform.action`, `_bookap.ID`, `_bookap.action`, `_accept.ID`, and `_accept.action`

Comment: I put the index on the ID column in the table I query. _inform.ID and _bookap.ID only exist in the query so do I need an index on them?  In which case how do I add that?

Comment: @highfidelity I don't get what you mean by `_inform.ID` and `_bookap.ID` "only exist in the query". Are these not column in those respective tables which relate to `_create.ID`?  You would add an index on these columns just as you did for `_create.ID` (excepting of course if this ID value needs to be a primary key or unique index in one of these tables rather than a standard index.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question (to return only one row) I would use an `ORDER BY` clause to sort your result set, followed by a `LIMIT 1` expression to only return one row.